# How do I get more than one autocomplete input field within a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I've managed to get the one autocomplete working, sifting through a list of 'Managers'... However, I have another field in need of autocompletion in the same form, returning a list of Companies. Is it possible to have more than one autocomplete within the same form?
I've tried importing another script, but that didn't seem to work.

template:

```
<label for="id_manager">Manager Username</label>
{{ form.manager }} // This autocomplete works
<label for="id_company">Company Name</label>
{{ form.company }} // This doesn't
```

forms.py:

```
manager = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-text', 'id':'id_managerbox'}), max_length=30, required=False)
company = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-text','id':'id_companybox'}))
```

This is the one Manager script that works. I have a separate one, for Company, nearly Identical.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('/autocomplete/managers/', function(data) {
        var completions = new Array();
        var dict = JSON.parse(data, function(key, value) {
            completions.push(key);
            return value;
        });
        $('#id_managerbox').autocomplete({
            source: completions,
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#id_manager').val(dict[ui.item.value]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Both Managers autocomplete and Company autocomplete have separate views.py
So my question: is there a way to throw 2 autocomplete scripts into one template? Is there a way of combining the 2 views into one js script result? (i'm sure I could rephrase that question better). Or am I going about this completely the wrong way? (Just to let you know, I'm not a js wizard.) Thank you so much for you help in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should check [django-autocomplete](https://bitbucket.org/tyrion/django-autocomplete), it could simplify your life.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of two autocompletes in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/822eZ/1/

You need to instance an autocomplete function for each input.

Comment: Thank you. But how am I to get the view for each instance. Am I calling `$.get('/autocomplete/managers/', function(data) {`, as well     `$.get('/autocomplete/companies/', function(data) {` ?